# Attach excel file to Notes and attachments in Salesforce using c#

Tags: c#, salesforce

I am not able to attach excel(.xls) file in "notes and attachments" section in specific record in Salesforce using c#. I am a beginner in salesforce. I will appreciate any kind of help. Thank you in advance.

Here's the code:

```
    const string qry = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Contact";
    var result=  sfdcBinding.query(qry);
    byte[] inbuff = File.ReadAllBytes(@"filename");

    Attachment attach = new Attachment();
    attach.Body = inbuff;
    attach.Name = "test";
    attach.IsPrivate = false;
    attach.Parent = result.records[0];
    attach.ParentId = result.records[0].Id;

    sObject[] InsertAttcment = new sObject[] { attach };

   sfdcBinding.create(InsertAttcment);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set both Parent and ParentId, you only need to set ParentId, so remove the attach.Parent line and you should be good to go

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked. I was trying using Oauth and I am using 
await forceClient.CreateAsync("Contact", attach);
Error Message: "No such column 'Body' on sobject of type Contact.

Comment: CreateAsync("Attachment", attach)

Comment: How to attach multiple files using loop?